# How to show the list items one by one when the function is running

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

My list control item will only be shown up when the function was stopped. I need to show the list control item one by one when the function is running.

Another function continually passes values to `HRESULT function()` until data processing is done.

```
//function to show the list item
HRESULT function(datetime, strNumOfGroup, strDisributionRegion, strSpeed){

  m_count = m_hyperTerminal.GetItemCount();

  items = m_hyperTerminal.InsertItem(m_count, datetime);// Five columns in the list control

  m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(items, 1, strNumOfGroup);
  m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(items, 2, strCompactness);
  m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(items, 3, strDistributionRegion);
  m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(items, 4, strSpeed);
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear (at least to me) what you're asking. Could you please provide the output you're getting from your code and the output you're expecting in detail?

Comment: The code snippet you've show is incorrect, it would not cpmpile at all. Please post real code. It's also un clear to me what you're asking. Please read this: [ask] and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is animation and it generally needs a second thread to update the display.

However using a second thread might be overkill. You may call `SetTimer` to update the window at fixed intervals. Then catch `WM_TIMER` messages, in `OnTimer` do all the updates in `OnTimer`. Once you are finished with the animation, call `KillTimer`

Example:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
    ...
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    ...
    SetTimer(1, 1000, NULL);
    return res;
}

void CMyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nid)
{
    CDialog::OnTimer(nid);
    if(nid == 1)
    {
        static int n = 0;
        if(n == 0) m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(0, 1, L"strNumOfGroup");
        if(n == 1) m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(0, 2, L"strCompactness");
        if(n == 2) m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(0, 3, L"strDistributionRegion");
        if(n == 3) m_hyperTerminal.SetItemText(0, 4, L"strSpeed");
        n++;
        if(n > 4)
            KillTimer(1);
    }
}
```